# CodeIntel with PHP in Sublime Text 2 not working

Tags: php, sublimetext2, sublimecodeintel

I am trying for 2 hours now to get SublimeCodeIntel working with PHP. Well, some things work, but CodeIntel doesnt autocomplete class methods and parameters when outside of the class.

I use Sublim Text 2 for Windows (7) and the last version of the plugin.

---

I have a class ***Page*** in ***classes/Page.php***, and a ***index.php***.
In index.php:

```
$page = new Page('home',$_GET['page']);
```

And when I type

```
$page->
```

I can read in taskbar **"Info: processing 'PHP': Please Wait"** for a few seconds and then nothing happens.

When working in ***Page.php***, I can start typing $this->.. and it somewhat works (actually it doesnt show functions parameters).
Same with Alt+clicking on functions and variables (only works if they are defined in the current file)

---

I tried several things:

**1/ Deactivating "detect_slow_plugins"** (error message doesn't appear anymore, but the plugin is not working better)

**2/ Changing SublimeCodeIntel.sublime-settings config** (copy paste the whole file and editing values):

```
"codeintel_language_settings": {
    "PHP": {
        "php": "E:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/bin",
        "codeintel_scan_extra_dir": [],
        "codeintel_scan_files_in_project": true,
        "codeintel_max_recursive_dir_depth": 15
    }
}
```

I don't even know if the "php" value is important (I found several snippets on the internet)...

**3/ Same thing in Sublim Text User settings**

**4/ Re-building indexes as advised [here](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel#regenerate-index)**

I use an PHP autoloader and I don't get how the plugin knows for sure which file defines which class. Could be an issue ?

I am completely stuck here, I tried everything I found, and read some setup tutorials (each one of them being something like "install and it just works!"... very annoying).

Does anyone have a solution? Or something to check, or try...
Thanks!

Comment: "I don't get how the plugin knows for sure which file defines which class" - it doesn't, until it's scanned all the files for the class definition, hence the "Please wait" message.

Comment: I see, thanks! So the problem should be that something goes wrong during the scan? The message shows for a few seconds so it is definitely doing something...